# asp.net asmx Webservice can't start

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a legacy asp.net web service who is part of a asp.net WebFroms application who is hosted on a WinServer 2008 R2. The asmx contains only this code:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/Src/FooWebService.vb" Class="FooWebService" %>
```

The FooWebService file is in the Folder Src and the service file itself is called FooWebService.asmx.

The FooWebService.vb has the following structure:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices

<ScriptService> _
<WebService(Namespace := "http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo := WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<DesignerGenerated>
Public Class FooWebService
    Inherits WebService

    <WebMethod>
    Public Function GetPLZ(prefixText As String) As String()
        ...
    End Function

    <WebMethod>
    Public Function GetStrasse(prefixText As String, contextKey As String) As String()
        ...
    End Function

    <WebMethod>
    Public Function HelloWorld() As String
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

When I try to access the WebService the following error message appears:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: can u post error message in english?

Comment: good point, sorry. changed it.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the service again? Please check if **FooWebService.vb** file and its dependencies are available.

Comment: Please post your namespace name, probably you have so set the class name fully qualified

Comment: how do you mean compile again? The FooWebService.vb is available. I added the structure of the vb class. @IrvinDominin the namespace of the vb file you can see above

Comment: Your "FooWebService" is problem in the wrong location, it seems to me that you have a mapping problem. Also man, change that default namespace FFS.

Comment: I moved the FooWebService back to the App_Code. That generated a App_Code.dll. With that it worked. Seems the Src folder wouldn't included somehow..